# Is it possible to have two different WhatsApp backups in the same iCloud account

Tags: icloud, backup

Currently I have WhatsApp backuped in my iCloud account. I want to change my phone number, not the iCloud account too. Still, I want to keep this backup. Is it possible to have in the same iCloud account two separate backups from two different WhatsApp numbers? Or the 2nd one will overwrite the 1st one and I will lose it?

Thank you very much!